# Laravel, Call to a member function sync() on null

Tags: laravel, fatal-error, eloquent

I have a FatalThrowableError in my laravel projects -  Call to a member function sync() on null. Debuger show mi, that is this line of code

```
Post::findOrFail($post_id)->tags()->sync([1, 2, 3], false);
```

Complete method this line look like:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
      // validate a post data
    $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|min:3|max:240',
            'body' => 'required|min:50',
            'category' => 'required|integer',
        ]);

    // store post in the database
    $post_id = Post::Create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'body' => $request->body,
    ])->id;

    Post::findOrFail($post_id)->tags()->sync([1, 2, 3], false);

    // rediect to posts.show pages
    return Redirect::route('posts.show', $post_id);
}
```

My Post model its looks like

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ ... ];

    public function category() {...}

    public function tags()
    {
       $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
    }
}
```

And my Tag model  its look like

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ ... ];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'post_tag', 'tag_id', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

Thanks for yours anser!

Comment: Your `tags()` method is missing a `return` statement:

`return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
// store post in the database
$post = new Post([
    'title' => $request->title,
    'body' => $request->body,
]);

$post->save();

$post->tags()->sync([1, 2, 3], false);
```

Comment: Thanks for yours anser, but this not solve my problem. I have this same error. After i tired: <br/>      `$post = new Post; <br/> 
        $post->title = $request->title;<br/> 
        $post->body = $request->body;<br/> 
       $post->save();<br/> 
        $post->tags()->sync([1, 2, 3], false); `<br/>

Comment: Are you able to insert new posts in posts table?? and why are you using [1,2,3] instead of $request->tags..

Comment: Yes, I'm correct creating a new post this table. I using [1, 2, 3] because this is simply test array, after fatal-error

Comment: try again by removing false in sync method

Comment: I try this before I asked this questions, and this unfortunately didn't work

Comment: ok fine the code looks fine and I used the same code in my projects and I don't face any issues. Can you put image of dd($post) before sync and image of your error message along with the question

Comment: I solved this problem, I just forgot using reserved word "return" in my tags() method in Post model. So dumb mistakes. Thanks a lot, for your time

Answer (score 3):

The error states that you're calling `sync()` on a null object, which means the result of your `tags()` method is `null`.

If you take a look at your `tags()` method, you can see that you forgot to `return` the relationship, therefore it is returning `null`. Add the `return` keyword and you should be good.

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
}
```